# KiCad 5 pins on wrong net in layout but not in schematic

Tags: kicad

One of my projects is stuck with KiCad 5 for now and I'm quite confused about the following...

Here is a part of my schematic. The 3.6V flag does not appear anywhere else, only these two positions.

---

[image: Sch]

---

**When** I generate a netlist file and load it in pcbnew (with all options ticked) it insists that the terminal pin 2 should be on the 3.3V net. Not the 3.6V one from the schematic. What am I doing wrong?

---

[image: DIalogue]
[image: Layout]

Comment: Strange. Try renaming it in schematic and forward annotate to PCB. Any difference?

Comment: Nothing. Tried both the "update from sch" button and the netlist file.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough information here to be able to help you.  The two nets are connected somewhere in the schematic (possibly by a broken wire where the GND line overlaps) but it will require searching.  If there is a hidden power input pin named "+3V6" that could also create a short with another net and not be immediately obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an alias on the 3v6 symbol called 3v3. That's it! Not sure really what they are for, but they don't exist any longer as of KiCad 6.
[image: Edit symbol]